# Smooth section of smooth vector bundle is generalization of graph of smooth map between two smooth manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I am reading (global) smooth sections of vector bundle. Let me define what do I mean by smooth section.

> Let $(E, M, \pi )$ be smooth (real) vector bundle of rank $k$ over smooth manifold $M$ where $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ be smooth surjective (projection) map. A smooth section of $E$ is smooth map $\sigma : M \rightarrow E$ such that $\pi(\sigma(p)) = p$.

I found in wikipedia page [Section (Fiber bunlde)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) that

> A section is an abstract characterization of what it means to be a graph. The graph of a smooth function $F : X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth real manifolds, can be identified with a function taking its values in the Cartesian product $E = X \times Y$, of $X$ and $Y$:
> \begin{align}
> \sigma : X \rightarrow E, \quad \sigma(x) = (x , g(x)) \in E
> \end{align}
> Let $\pi : E \rightarrow X $ be the projection onto the first factor: $\pi(x , y) = x$. Then the graph is any function $\sigma$ for which $\pi(\sigma(x)) = x$.

Thus we need to check that $E = X \times Y$ is vector bundle over $X$, because then we can talk about its section. That is first I need to check: for each $x \in X$ the $\pi^{-1}(x) = \{x\} \times Y$ is a real vector space.

At this stage, I am stuck. Someone please explain me how to give real vector space structure on $\{x \} \times Y$.

Comment: In general $X \times Y \to X$ *isn't* a vector bundle (unless $Y$ itself carries a vector space structure).

Comment: @TravisWillse Okay. Then how to justify whatever is written above/wikipedia page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; the excerpt you cite concerns general fiber bundles and not just vector bundles.